# Deserializing MongoDB $oid using jackson library

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I have a very simple POJO that I write to MongoDB. It then returns me JSON that includes the _id property as an $oid object. I'd like to write it into my POJO, but so far have failed. I've seen many people struggle with it and suggesting different solutions, but I have yet to get any of them to work. Probably because nobody provides exact details which libraries they are actually using. There's codehaus.jackson.* there's com.fastxml.jackson.*, jongo, org.mongo.*, com.mongo.* etc.

My object looks like this:

```
package com.blueplanetsoftware.metrics.rest;

import javax.persistence.Id;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class MongoObject
{
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    private String _id;

    @JsonProperty("userID")
    private String userID;
    @JsonProperty("appID")
    private String appID;  
    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message = "";
    @JsonProperty("session")
    private String session;

    public MongoObject() {}

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    @Id
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    public String getId()
    {
        return _id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    @Id
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this._id = id;
    }
}
```

The JSON that I get back looks like this:

```
{ 
  "userID" : "aap" ,
  "appID" : "noot" , 
  "message" : "JSON" , 
  "session" : "ea944555b5ea8ea6" , 
  "_id" : { "$oid" : "5245f1063004348555e54815"}
}
```

when I try to deserialize that JSON into my class with this code:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
MongoObject o = mapper.readValue(response, MongoObject.class);
```

it gives me an exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@456c1227; line: 1, column: 93] (through reference chain: com.blueplanetsoftware.metrics.rest.MongoObject["_id"])
```

So how to get the _id / $oid string into my _id property? I'm surprised there's isn't an easy way to do this. At least I haven't found any so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
@ObjectId @Id 
private String id;
```

I've written a test to see this working:

```
@Test
public void shouldConvertJSONStringIntoPojo() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MongoObject actual = mapper.readValue("{\n" +
                                     "        \"userID\" : \"aap\" ,\n" +
                                     "        \"appID\" : \"noot\" ,\n" +
                                     "        \"message\" : \"JSON\" ,\n" +
                                     "        \"session\" : \"ea944555b5ea8ea6\" ,\n" +
                                     "        \"_id\" : { \"$oid\" : \"5245f1063004348555e54815\"}\n" +
                                     "}", MongoObject.class);

    assertThat(actual, equalTo(new MongoObject("5245f1063004348555e54815", "aap", "noot", "JSON", "ea944555b5ea8ea6")));
}
```

The libraries I'm using for this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; (jackson-databind-2.1.4,jar)
import org.junit.Test;                              (junit-4.11.jar)
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;    (hamcrest-core-1.3.jar)
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;          (junit-4.11.jar)
```

The only changes I've made to your MongoObject posted in the question is adding a constructor that takes all the fields, and hashCode, equals & toString (so I can test it).  If I run that test with that MongoObject, then I get the same error as you:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@7a7ff2aa; line: 5, column: 40] (through reference chain: MongoObject["_id"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:599)
```

But if I make one small change to your MongoObject:

```
public class MongoObject
{
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    @org.jongo.marshall.jackson.oid.ObjectId
    private String _id;

    @JsonProperty("userID")
    private String userID;
    @JsonProperty("appID")
    private String appID;
    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message;
    @JsonProperty("session")
    private String session;

    public MongoObject() {}

//... insert constructors, hashCode, equals and toString just for testing...
}
```

Then the test passes.

Comment: I think I tried that. However, @ObjectId is from the MongoJack library. While MongoJack seems fine to turn your MongoDB query directly into POJOs, I couldn't find how to turn a JSON string into a POJO using MongoJack or vice-versa. Since I'm making a REST service that's platform and language agnostic, my REST code needs to return JSON strings. On the client side, when using Java, I want to turn those strings into a POJO. That's where the _id : {$0id : "abc"} construct is giving trouble. Am I missing something trivial here?

Comment: I think the one I was using was from Jongo, which is great for queries.  MongoJack is not the same as Jongo.  In MongoJack, you can give the JacksonDBCollection the POJO to save, but I guess that still doesn't answer your problem, as you still need to get the POJO.  In my project, Jackson Data Bindings seems to be taking care of that side of things.  I'll update my answer with the junit test I wrote, in case that helps.

Comment: Thanks Trisha, that works indeed. Which I find very curious because it doesn't work without the @org.jongo.marshall.jackson.oid.ObjectId annotation. Even though this is the only reference to Jongo. Does that mean that the com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper knows about Jongo annotations? There's something magical about this solution that doesn't make sense.  But at least it solves my problem, I'll see if I can understand it later.

Comment: I'm not sure off the top of my head how/why it works.  There's probably some version of Jackson that would work instead.

Comment: Isn't it easier to deserialize _id in an ObjectId rather than a String? just tested and ..no

Comment: I was running into this same problem today and did a bit of digging. The Jongo @ObjectId works because it directly applies a [custom deserializer](https://github.com/bguerout/jongo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jongo/marshall/jackson/oid/ObjectIdDeserializer.java) [directly to the field](https://github.com/bguerout/jongo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jongo/marshall/jackson/oid/ObjectId.java). MongoJack uses a [similar deseralizer](https://github.com/mongojack/mongojack/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mongojack/internal/ObjectIdDeserializers.java) but doesn't apply it directly.